# How do I find my Google App Engine SDK installation

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I am following a tutorial (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) on using google app engine to deploy from gradle. 
It say to point to your local installation of Google App Engine SDK. Except I don't really know how to find this, how would I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following an older tutorial. Please use the [new tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin) for the new gradle plugin as your point of reference. The new tutorial does not require this information.

In regards to your question location of the SDK, it depends on the Operating System.

You can run the command `gcloud info` which will detail about the installation. See `Installation Properties` for more details about the install path.